# SqlCeReader hangs when query returns 0 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, sqldatareader, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm developing for Windows Mobile 6.5, with Sql Compact Edition 3.5 SP2 (3.5.1, aka 3.5.8080.0).

When my query nets > 1 result, `reader.Read()` returns the expected non-zero value (allowing the `while` loop to proceed).  But if there is no matching data in the table, and the query results in 0 rows returned, the call to `reader.Read()` blocks indefinitely.  I'd expect the opposite, that it'd return 0 immediately, bypassing the `while` loop.

```
   SqlCeCommand cmd = mValidationDB.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT CLEI FROM Validation WHERE PartCode='{0}' OR CLEI='{0}'", barCode);
   SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
       string result = reader.GetString(0);
       return result;
   }
   return "";
```

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably the `reader` is null if there's no data to be read.

Comment: I've confirmed that is not null.  And, unfortunately, HasRows is not implemented in v3.5, so I'm not sure how else to check for valid data before calling Read().

Comment: What build of 3.5 is in use?

Comment: @ErikEJ In Add Reference, it shows as 3.5.5386.0.  Once it has been added, the Version in the Reference Properties is just 3.5.0.0 (but the paths are identical).

Comment: Seeing that there was an SP2 available, I just tried that as well (3.5.8080.0, v3.5.1 in the properties).  No change, drat.